# window.requestAnimationFrame using object and this keyword

Tags: javascript, animation, this, game-engine, requestanimationframe

I am learning the basics of a physics engine using javascript and wanting to have all of the engine and the game data held within an object, but have been unable to use the 'this' keyword when recursively calling the draw function to animate the scene. I can successfully call the separate draw function that works, but won't be as easy to implement more than one object to animate

here is a simple [codepen](http://codepen.io/synthet1c/details/fesuw) with a working testbed.

here is the page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">

    #obj{
        width: 50px;
        height: 200px;
        background: red;
        position: absolute;
        left: 100px;
        bottom: 200px;
    }

    #ground{
        width: 100%;
        height: 200px;
        background: #222;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
    }

</style>


</head> 

<body>

<div id="content">

<section>
    <button onclick="draw()">draw()</button><br>
    <button onclick="obj.draw()">obj.draw()</button>
</section>

<article>

    <div id="obj"></div>
    <div id="ground"></div>

</article>  

</div> <!-- END CONTENT -->

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">

var obj = {
    // variables
    id: 'obj',
    width: 50,
    height: 200,
    angle: 30,
    speed: 20,
    acceleration: 4/60,
    deceleration: 2/60,
    moving: false,
    jumping: false,
    // Get methods
    x: function(){return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(this.id)).left)},
    y: function(){return parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(this.id)).bottom)},
    // engine methods
    scale_x: function(){return Math.cos((this.angle * Math.PI) / 180)},
    scale_y: function(){return Math.sin((this.angle * Math.PI) / 180)},
    velocity_x: function(){return this.speed * this.scale_x()},
    velocity_y: function(){return this.speed * this.scale_y()},
    cx: function(){return this.x() + this.width},
    cy: function(){return this.y() + this.height},
    // set methods
    setAngle: function(val){this.angle = val},
    setAcceleration: function(val){this.acceleration = val / 60},
    setDeceleration: function(val){this.deceleration = val / 60},
    setSpeed: function(val){this.speed = val},
    setMoving: function(val){this.moving = val},
    setJumping: function(val){this.jumping = val},
    draw: function(){
        document.getElementById(this.id).style.left = (this.speed++) + 'px';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.draw);
    }
}

function draw(){
    document.getElementById(obj.id).style.left = (obj.speed++) + 'px';
        window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

</script>   

</html>
```

thanks for any help,

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that you call `obj.draw` as :

```
<button onclick="obj.draw()
```

The first time obj.draw is called, the context is different than when it called by [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame) multiple times, as a callback function before the repaint.

So try by saving **this** in a variable which is outside the scope of the callback function.

Something like :

```
var obj = {    
    //...

    draw: function () {
        var sender = this;
        var draw = function () {
            document.getElementById(sender.id).style.left = (sender.speed++) + 'px';
            window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        }
        draw();
    }
}
```

Here is an [updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Auw5u/) of how this would look like.

Comment: brilliant thanks for explaining that, I did see a couple of other threads about this problem, but that was the best example